# SVG to PDF using svglib

Tags: python, svg, reportlab

I am trying to convert `SVG` to `PDF` in python using `svglib` and `reportlab`.So,I installed both of these,and following is the example on their [site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/) and I ran it exactly as it is,like below.

```
>>> from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
>>> from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
>>> drawing = svg2rlg("SVGMonitor.svg")
Failed to load input file!
```

I get this error `Failed to load input file!`.Please suggest what could be the problem?

The `svg` file I am trying to convert is a valid file, and also has enough permissions.

Using python 2.6

Comment: if `"SVGMonitor.svg"` dows not appear when you do `import os;print os.listdir('.')` then you are in the wrong directory.

Comment: Could you please paste the whole error?

Comment: @User:I am in the correct directory,verified that.
I did not get anything else other than this error.I just got 1 line as the output and that is `Failed to load input file!`,nothing else.

Comment: Use an `absolute path` for your SVG and see if it goes away or not.

Comment: @SamRad: I have tried that already.

Comment: @g4ur4v, would you include your SVG in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as answer because it is too long:

This is the function you call:

```
# from http://philip-tzou-code-art.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PDF/svglib.py
def svg2rlg(path):
    "Convert an SVG file to an RLG Drawing object."

    # load SVG file
    try:
        doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(path)
        svg = doc.documentElement
    except: 
                       # try except is really a bad thing like this
        print "Failed to load input file!"
        #return

    # convert to a RLG drawing
    svgRenderer = SvgRenderer(path)
    svgRenderer.render(svg)
    drawing = svgRenderer.finish()

    return drawing
```

try it with `try` and `except` removed. What does it do?